# Data from POST request not passed from template/form to view in django

Tags: python, django, post

Actually, I’m not really sure what the problem exactly is, but I think data from the form/template is not being passed to the view in my Django app.

Running a test gives:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

The form:

```
    <form action="/{{ link.id }}/{{ node.id }}/" method="post" class="comment-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
            {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

The view:

```
def comments(request, link_id, comment_id=None):
    link = get_object_or_404(Link, pk=link_id)
    if comment_id is not None:
        parent = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=comment_id)
    else:
        parent = None
    comments = link.comments.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            form = CommentForm(data=request.POST,auto_id=True)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.full_clean()
                new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
                new_comment.link = link
                new_comment.parent = parent
                new_comment.save()
                return reverse('comments', kwargs={'link_id':link.id,'comment_id':parent.id})
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login/?next=/{0}/'.format(link.id))
    else:
        form = CommentForm(auto_id=True)
        return render(request, 'posts/comments.html', {'nodes':comments, 'link': link, 'form': form})
```

The full [relevant code is here](https://gist.github.com/Flobin/dcdffc84349c731dbc34), because it’s maybe a bit much for one stackoverflow post. (Is there a guideline for this?)

here's the (working, for now) [project](https://github.com/Flobin/parrot/commit/946faa294092f7aeb58c04bf70c3a6fe3dd1d719).

Comment: You don't need to include all the code from your project, but the full traceback is usually helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the key part of the traceback.

```
    File "/Users/robin/learning/python/parrot/posts/views.py", line 42, in comments
return reverse('comments', kwargs={'link_id':link.id,'comment_id':parent.id})
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Since `link` cannot be None, that suggests that `parent` is `None`. Perhaps you need to use a different url if `parent_id` is None.

The view should return an `HttpResponse`, not a url. I think you want:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('comments', kwargs={'link_id':link.id,'comment_id':parent.id}))
```

or you can use the `redirect` shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import reverse
return redirect('comments', link_id=link.id, comment_id=parent.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You state in your view:

```
    if comment_id is not None:
        parent = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=comment_id)
    else:
        parent = None
```

but it seems you never pass `comment_id`, just `link_id`, therefore in this line:

```
return reverse('comments', kwargs={'link_id':link.id,'comment_id':parent.id})
```

`parent` is always None.

It would help to see your url mappings as well as CommentForm.